# If C6/2 is less than .5, then E6 will be .5 otherwise the answer is C6/2

Tags: excel

I would like to have a formula to answer the following:

If C6/2 is less than .5, then E6 will be .5 otherwise the answer is C6/2.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with the equivalent (but smaller) statement `=IF(C6<1,.5,C6/2)`

What you're doing has another name it's called the `max` function. `=MAX(C6/2,.5)` will produce the same result but is much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

How about `=IF(C6/2<.5,.5,C6/2)`?  Place in E6.